# How to enlarge the line title in my gnuplot plot

Tags: gnuplot, title

```
set xtics 
set ytics 0.025
set xlabel 'Aeroelastic cycles' font ",17"
set ylabel'Max deformation(m)' font ",17"
set grid
p 'deform20.conv' u 1:6 w lp title 'with tethers' , 'deform19.conv' u 1:6 w lp title 'without tethers'
```

thats the code of my plot and i would like to big the titles of my lines (with tethers , without tethers).
Could you help me?[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTk1U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the manual or in gnuplot console type `help key`.

For example:

```
set key font ",20"
```

will enlarge your key.